# Autoencoder Decoded Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to build an AutoEncoder, where I am trying to de-noise the signal.

Now, for example, the amplitude range of my input signal varies in between -47 to +32. But while I am getting the decoded signal (reconstructed one), that signal only ranges in between 0 to +1 amplitude.

How can I get my reconstructed signal with the same amplitude range of  -47 to +32?

Comment: You can just scale the output, like `output * (32 - (-47)) + (-47)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the question is whether your returned signal is a faithful representation of the input signal (but it's just constrained to the range 0 to 1)?

If so, you could simply multiply it by 79, and then subtract 47.

We'd need to see code if it's more than just a scaling issue.